# Google Analytics - Filter Field Request URI

Tags: filter, google-analytics, analytics

In Google Analytics Acquisition Source, I often see different referral sources from Facebook and they look like this:
   `m.facebook.com / referral`
   `l.facebook.com / referral`
   `facebook.com / referral`

I want to use filter to merge all of these into

`facebook.com`

I tried putting search string & replace string but it doesn't work out.
How can I do this please?

Comment: Can you show us how you configured your filter?

Comment: I choose Search and Replace > Filter Field: Request URI > Search String: `l.facebook` > Replace String: `facebook`